# Vim - move rest of line to new line above

Tags: vim

How does one get from

```
int lel = 123; // this is a comment
               ^
```

to

```
// this is a comment
int lel = 123;
```

preferably when starting in insert mode, and with the right indentation?

My current way of doing it is `C-c l d$ O C-c p`, but as my auto-indent isn't perfect, the inserted line in not indented at all.

I think some editors use `space+enter` or something for this (at least I *think* I've seen it).

Is this possible in vim by default?

Comment: Your current way doesn't work!

Comment: If you just want to reindent a line, the command is `==`.

Comment: Oops, no it doesn't! Fixed now. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Still not a very pretty answer, but assuming the cursor is where the "^" is above, another option would be:

<kbd>d</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>=</kbd><kbd>:</kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>u</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

- `d0` deletes til the beginning of the line.
- `=` reindents over the next motion.
- `:pu` short for `:put`
- `Enter` to run the command.

Comment: I tried that too, but at least for me the text ends up in column 1 on both lines.

Comment: Can you create an example file?  It works for me with pretty much no vim configuration, indent settings or otherwise, on a C-ish file.

Comment: I put `foo; // bar` in a `.c` file and indented the line. I also tried `d^`, no joy. I started a clean Vim session, same result.

Comment: In that case, both lines *should* end up beginning in column 1 as that is not a case where the text should be indented in a C file.  Try throwing that same text inside a `void main(){}` block and it should be indented.  The use of the `=` command is re-indenting both lines to the expected indentation level for the language in use.  If you want it to copy your current indentation then this will have to be modified pretty radically before it will work for you.

Comment: Oh well you see I'm as stupid as a very stupid person. Yes, if there is a previous indented line or a surrounding block, both lines end up indented for me as well. I actually knew that, my train of thought just didn't stop at that station. Sorry.

Comment: This worked when in a .c file, but when I tested it in a .py file, it wouldn't indent right (I'm guessing vim somehow messes up python indentation?).

Comment: That's probably because of the significance of whitespace in Python not meshing well with auto-reindentation (`=`).  I'd suggest writing a function that handles this and just mapping it to a key.  I very much doubt that any solution here is going to be right 100% of the time.

Answer (score 3):

I would probably use

```
DO<c-r>"
```

`D` deletes to the end of line. `O` opens the line above in insert mode (with the correct indentation). `<c-r>"` pastes the part that was deleted with `D`.

(This ends in insert mode)

Comment: this seems to mess up formatting for me sometimes so I use `==` afterwards, but it's better than what I was doing before, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**New answer:**

```
d^o<c-u><esc>p
```

Figured it out. This was one of my early attempts, but in the form `<esc>d^o<esc>p`, which has the problem that the inserted line gets a comment leader. `<c-u>` fixes that.

```
d^o<c-u><c-o>p
```

is of course useful if one wants to stay in Insert mode.

---

**Earlier answer:**

*This solution works, but the answer by Randy Morris is better.*

Suggested key sequence:

```
<esc>mpa<cr><esc>dd`pP`pa
```

(Where `p` can be replaced with any other mark.)

This means `<esc>` enter Normal mode, `mp` mark current position as `p`, `a` enter Insert mode, `<cr>` break the line and put the comment on the next line at the correct indentation, `<esc>` go to Normal mode, `dd` delete line, `` `p `` go to the marked position, `P` put the deleted line before the current line, `` `p `` go to the marked position, `a` go to Insert mode. To avoid wearing your fingers out, map it:

```
:inoremap <F2> <esc>mpa<cr><esc>dd`pP`pa
```

The indentation will not be correct if the comment is at the end of a line that increases or decreases indentation.

**Simpler sequence that will not work on the last line in the buffer**

To perform this operation on a line that isn't the last line in the buffer, the following will do. With the cursor on the first slash, in Insert mode: `<cr><esc>ddkPjA`.

The `<cr>` breaks the line and puts the comment at the correct indentation, `<esc>` go to Normal mode, `dd` delete line, `k` go to previous line, `P` put the deleted line before the current line, `jA` to end up in Insert mode where you were when you started.

To map it:

```
:inoremap <F2> <cr><esc>ddkPjA
```

Comment: This gets rid of my indentation problems, but it's still quite a few keystrokes.

Comment: <F2> is one keystroke.

Comment: @KingMob the map was edited in after my commend. Also, I'm aware of maps, but I wanted to know it it's possible without one! :)

Comment: what is <c-u>? ctrl + u? it isn't in my help and that keystroke scrolls up half a page

Comment: @connor: to find it in help, use `:help i_CTRL-U`. Basically, it removes newly entered text / any text before the cursor, in this case the comment leader. It's a bit of a scatterbrain answer anyway.